# Solr4.0 testing EmbeddedSolrServer using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, solr, lucene

I am unable to test the EmbeddedSOlrServer and I run into following exception

> Exception in thread main
>   java.lang.NoClassDEfFOundError:org/apache/lucene/codecs/PostingFormat
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.reloadLuceneSPI(SolrResourceLoader.java:179)

Code -

> System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", "c:/apps/solr4/example/solr");
>   CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
>   CoreContainer coreContainer = initializer.initialize();
>   EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "");

I believe I have all jars in class path and `solr.solr.home` setting is also updated. Please advise

Comment: Are there more details in the logs? and if you can, it would be nice to see the code which throws this exception, for giving you more accurate advices

Comment: System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", "c:/apps/solr4/example/solr");
CoreContainer.Initializer initializer = new CoreContainer.Initializer();
CoreContainer coreContainer = initializer.initialize();
EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "");

Comment: Got it working by adding lucene jars one by one.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem adding the lucene-core dependency into the test scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```